# Jupyter notebook Import tensorflow_hub error: No module named tensorflow.python.training.tracking

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow-hub

I am using the Deep Learning AMI (Amazon Linux) Version 27.0 for TensorFlow 2(+Keras2) with Python3 (CUDA 10.1 and Intel MKL-DNN). I installed tensorflow_hub through

```
python3 -m install tensorflow_hub latest
```

But when I import it to the Jupyter notebook I get the below error. Any ideas what this error might mean?

[image: error]

Comment: which version of TF 2.x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: I uninstalled all previous TensorFlow versions and installed specifically Tensorflow 2.0 like this:

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow 
pip3 install tensorflow==2.0
pip3 install tensorflow_hub latest
```